# Tuning time estimates in Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, estimation

Cura consistently under-estimates my print times. I know I'm not alone here, but I've also noticed it seems most of the difference comes from travel and retraction times... that is, if I re-slice an object to minimize those operations the accuracy of the estimate improves. Also, the estimates seem more accurate for objects which require less travel and retraction than those which require more.

Is there a way in Cura to adjust how it counts time for those operations, and thereby improve the accuracy of my time estimates?

Comment: I think this question is somewhat related to [*Estimating printing time from Cura*](/q/4066) and is [answered by Tim Kuipers](/a/4440).

Comment: @0scar: In Cura if acceleration and jerk are disabled (leave machine defaults alone), what values are used for estimating? The machine limits? Or the set values of the disabled options?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE maybe it is better to comment on the answer of Tim Kuipers, he is or has been involved in Cura development.

Comment: @0scar: Done. Thanks for suggesting that. I'm having lots of trouble with bad estimates and I'd like to figure this out too.